# How do I get inside Papyrus's shed?

Tags: undertale

I've been playing a pacifist route in Undertale, and I've noticed that Papyrus's shed seems to be permanently locked with no way to enter it.

I assume that there may be some way to enter it in a Genocide run, but is there any way to enter the shed if I'm playing pacifist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you lose to Papyrus when challenging him on a peaceful run, he will put you inside the shed.  There's not much of interest in there.

Comment: If you lose multiple times, however, the note he leaves will keep changing.

Comment: Also the dog bowl will contain a hot dog instead of kibble. (Also, the note will have a unique message when you try to read it by save editing yourself inside the shed.)

Comment: The peacefulness of the run is irrelevant, as far as I can tell.  You can't lose to him on Genocide for *reasons*, and losing to him in either other route causes you to be "captured".  The other comments mean I need to go lose to Paps a few times now...